# PlayStore requires 103mb free space to install an APK of only 8.5mb

Tags: android, apk

I have 3 builds for the same app. 2 of them have size of 30mb (100 installed) but the one targeting SDK 23+ has only 8.5mb. In fact this APK expands to 16mb only when installed.

In the app download page it's written "Download size: 8.5mb" but if you try to install it to a device with less than 103mb available storage, you will get a message like this: "This download requires at least 103mb of free storage" and then it will show a list of apps to uninstall.

So is this is a bug of PlayStore or am I doing something wrong? Is there any good workaround?

Comment: Seems off topic